# Is there a method that concatenates two wil::unique_bstr string in WinRT?

Tags: c++-winrt, wil

There is a Windows Implementation Library (wil), documentation available in github [text](https://github.com/microsoft/wil.git), that provides wrapper class for bstr that allows manipulation of BSTR.
I am porting my legacy code to WinRT component where i have replaced CComBSTR with wil::unique_bstr.
In my code, it appends two strings by using a += b;
Is there a method in WIL library for appending two unique_bstr?, any pointer is appreciated.

I have tried converting bstr with std::wstring and do the entire manipulation with STL, however, that needs to be changed too many places. So I want to use bstr and append two bstr.

Comment: There's [`wil::str_concat()`](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/String-helpers#wilstr_concat), but it doesn't seem like it supports `BSTR`s. Maybe the documentation is out of date, so that's worth a try. If that cannot be done you can implement your own `operator+`.

Comment: Worth noting, `BSTR`s (like their WinRT pendant `HSTRING`) are immutable. There is no API for string concatenation. `CComBSTR` simulates concatenation by allocating a new `BSTR` of sufficient length, copies the previous contents over, appends the new string, and then frees the previously allocated string. If you need to implement `operator+=`, that's what you'd need to do as well.

Comment: Thanks, I have used combination of wil::unique_bstr and std::wstring,    internal implementation is changed to use std::wstring and final result is returned using wil::unique_bstr.